# How to filter log records in an application?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a WinForms application with log4net.
The app.config has a log4net configuration section. It contains settings like this:

```
<appender name="coloredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

But user wants to change  levelMin and levelMax via GUI menu because edit app.config file is not comfortable.
How can I change the levelMin and levelMax values in application?

Comment: There are _a lot_ of questions about configuring log4net programmatically on SO. I couldn't find a 1:1 dupe as of now, but searching may give you at least some hints.

Comment: I'd like to use app.config file but only provide the possibility to change the filter levels programmatically  for the current app session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4net can be configured by config file and later the application can correct parameters like this:

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Error;
hierarchy.Configured = true;
```